# Disable alert sound for notifications in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, notifications

I am using the following code to show Notification in Firefox:

```
var options = {
  body: 'Do you like my body?',
  silent: true
}

var n = new Notification('Test notification',options);
```

In Chrome it works as expected i.e the notification is silent but in Firefox the sound still comes. Can you let me know what I am missing?

I want the Notification to be silent with code only instead doing some external setting in Browser.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491672/disable-default-alert-sound-for-firefox-web-notifications

Comment: See my Answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674299/3696510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the Browser [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Browser_compatibility) on MDN, the `silent` option is still not available in Firefox.

> noscreen, renotify, silent, sound, and sticky options:    No support

Note that `silent` option is available from Chrome 43.

Comment: You are right, so there is no other way to make it silent?

Comment: Now using using the `silent` option is not possible. But you should check later, because it is a planned implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your support.